# Should a setState function be a dependency of useEffect when passed via hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, closures

So, I've stumbled upon this weird situation:

I have a global React Context provider, providing a global state, like so

```
const Context = createContext();

const ContextProvider = ({children}) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState('');
  return <Context.Provider value={{state, setState}}>{children}</Context.Provider>
}

const useMyState = () => {
  const {state, setState} = useContext(Context);

  return {
   state,
   setState
  }
}

const Component = () => {
  const {setState} = useMyState();

  useEffect(() => {
   elementRef.addEventListener('click', () => {
    setState('someState');
   });

   return () => {
    elementRef.removeEventListener('click', () => null); 
   }
  },[])

return <>
 // ...
</>
}
```

`eslint` suggests that my `setState` should be added to the `useEffect`'s dependency array,

```
useEffect(() => {
   elementRef.addEventListener('click', () => {
    setState('someState');
   });
  },[setState])
```

I'm guessing that this might be somehow related to the destructuring of the context inside the `useMyState.ts` file

but that feels a bit weird and non-intuitive...

my question is is the `setState` really required inside the dependency array? and if so, why?

Comment: Couple things: you should at least provide an empty dependency array, otherwise, the effect runs every update. [State setters identity is guaranteed to be stable](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate), so there's no need to pass them as dependency, though it doesn't hurt. You should memoize the context value since every render of the context will trigger a re-render in every consumers.

Comment: Before you worry about adding `setState` in the dependency array, you should atleast have an empty array; not doing so will cause the `useEffect` to execute after each component re-render, leading to adding a new event listener after each re-render. To answer your question, `setState` is guaranteed to not change; so  it is not required to add it in the dependency array but there is no harm in adding it in the dependency array. At the very least, it will silence the eslint warning.

Comment: @Yousaf - The array should have `elementRef.current` in it, since they use that in the callback.

Comment: Sorry, actual code has the missing cleanup and dependency array, I've somehow neglected them in the attached code example, edited now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> my question is is the `setState` really required inside the dependency array?

No, it isn't, but ESLint doesn't know that, because it has no way to know that the `setState` member of the context object you're using is stable. **You** know that (because the setter is guaranteed to be stable by `useState`, and you're passing it verbatim through context and your `useMyState` hook), but ESLint doesn't know that.

You can add it as a dependency to make ESLint happy (it won't make any difference if you're already providing an array, because the setter never changes; see below if you're *not* providing an array), or you can put in a comment to tell ESLint to skip checking that code, or you can turn the rule off (but it's **very** easy to miss out dependencies, so be careful if you do).

(If you're not providing an array [because you want the effect to run after every render], adding an array with the setter in it will stop that from happening, so you'll want to go with the option of disabling the ESLint error for that one situation. Or there are icky solutions like using a ref with an ever-increasing number value in it. :-) )

---

There is a problem with that code, though. It's repeatedly adding new event listeners to the element without ever removing them, because with **no** dependency array, the `useEffect` callback is called every time the component renders, and you're creating a new event handler function every time, so they'll stack up.

So you'll need to make `elementRef.current` a dependency, and you'll need a cleanup callback:

```
const Component = () => {
    const {setState} = useMyState();
  
    useEffect(() => {
        const handler = () => {
            setState("someState");
        };
        const element = elementRef.current;
        // Note −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^^^^^^^^
        element.addEventListener("click", handler);
        return () => {
            element.removeEventListener("click", handler);
        };
    }, [elementRef.current]); // <== Optionally add `setState` to this

    return <>
        // ...
    </>;
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!, I'm aware of the missing `removeEventListener`, they are there in actual code I just neglected them in the demo code

Comment: @MarikSh - My pleasure! And good, good, :-) (I just fixed a bug with my updated version of your code. If you don't see `const element = ...` in the `useEffect` callback, hit refresh. :-) )